# How do I make ink appear while drawing in powerpoint presenter mode?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I am using a Surface Pro 4 with powerpoint to make presentations. When I make annotations using the pen, they appear as a single shape after I've completed the drawing.

For example, if I circle a word the audience will not see me circling it, but only the circle once it is complete. Is there a way to have the audience see me writing? I feel that is much more natural to follow.

Comment: I'm afraid this is "by design"

Comment: Indeed. The only way is by using a movie clip, which means you'll get a powerpoint presentation of several hundred megabytes, or more...

Comment: Drawing in powerpoint is totally useless because of this :-(